# Modify Wicket's PagingNavigator Tooltip and text of first,last,next,prev buttons

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, wicket

I would like to modify the text and Tooltip of the first,last,next,prev buttons in Wicket.

By default the text of the buttons is displayed with "<<" "<" ">" ">>" 
I have placed icons using CSS in the buttons. But I can't find a way to remove the button's text (those arrow text chars)

Also the buttons have a title. This title is set in the PagingNavigator class.
It does not seem to me like there is a way to modify the Tooltip / title of the buttons.
We don't use property files, I would like to set a custom Tooltip using a setter method.

Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Thanks

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way is to create your own subclass of `PagingNavigator`, e.g. `MyPagingNavigator`:

```
public class MyPagingNavigator extends PagingNavigator {
  public MyPagingNavigator(final String id, final IPageable pageable) {
    super(id, pageable);
  }
}
```

No other code changes are necessary.

You can then *copy* the original markup into your own `MyPagingNavigator.html` file and customize the text and anything else (as long as you leave the component hierarchy intact.

Comment: Thanks we did solve it just like that. And for the issue with the Tooltips I am using now a custom IStringResourceLoader.